# what packages do I need to install to draw traceplot in R

Tags: r

I need to draw a traceplot in R but I don't have a package that has "traceplot"
what pacakages do I need to install?

Comment: Can you show what code you have run that you now want to show in a traceplot. e.g. if you are doing some modelling in  rjags or nimble you probably want to use the `coda` package (although it is easy to run a traceplot on any matrix using as.mcmc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `coda::traceplot()` or `plotMCMC::plotTrace()`.  (`coda` is probably the "canonical", i.e. the oldest/best-established/most-used, package for this application.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `library (bpnreg)`

E.g.:

```
library(bpnreg)
fit.Motor <- bpnr(pred.I = Phaserad ~ 1 + Cond, data = Motor,
its = 100, burn = 10, n.lag = 3)
traceplot(fit.Motor, parameter = "beta1")
```

[image]

If you like an aestetics of `ggplot2` - look the `library(ggmcmc)`.

See examples **there:**

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmcmc/vignettes/using_ggmcmc.html