# R- How to draw traceplot?

Tags: r

I got 1000 values for the 1000 iterations but I don't know how to draw a traceplot using the 1000values in R.
the structure of data is here.
I want to draw a traceplot about w11

```
aa <- matrix(w_list, ncol = 6, nrow = 1000,byrow=TRUE)
w11=aa[1:1000,1]
```

w11 is like

```
print(w11)

[[1]]
1.55

[[2]]
1.56
.
.
.
[[999]]
[1] 1.552087

[[1000]]
[1] 1.55214
```

In this case, How can I draw a traceplot?

Comment: what have you tried since your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69507765/what-packages-do-i-need-to-install-to-draw-traceplot-in-r) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69528548/how-to-draw-a-traceplot-of-weights-in-forward-back-propagation-in-r) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69559110/how-to-get-values-of-weights-during-iteration-and-draw-a-traceplot-in-r) questions about trace plots?

Comment: I tried to change the column into a vector and made new data frame and drew a ggplot but it did not work

Comment: how do you generate ```w_list```?